# Is there a way to run Dart in Firefox for development purposes?

Tags: firefox, dart, dart-pub

I know you can run Dart code natively in your browser using Dartium (Chrome with an embedded Dart VM), and you can compile your Dart to JavaScript.

But seeing I prefer using Firefox for web development, is there a way to run Dart code directly in Firefox? For example via a plugin or extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.
I also haven't heard of any plans yet.
You can use `pub serve` which transpiles to JavaScript automatically, but this is rather slow.

You could make a feature request for Firefox, to make them aware of the demand.

Comment: The dart2js transformer used by `pub serve` can be customized: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dart2js-transformer.html Maybe there's still room for optimizing the speed. I haven't tried it though.